# Common normal for an ellipse and parabola

Tags: conic-sections, coordinate-systems

I came across the following question in a magazine with example problems for the JEE examination in India:

> Given are two curves $x^2/a^2 + y^2/63=1$ and $y^2=4x$.
>
> The maximum integral value of $a$ for which there is only one common normal to the two curves is:
>
> A. 7
> B. 8
> C. 9
> D. 10

My attempts so far:

1. I came up with an equation for the normal of an ellipse in terms of slope, and one for parabola, then solved them, but the calculations got really messy.
2. Used a graph plotter, but could not digest the fact that they have a common normal.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: You should write your results in more details. Messy calculations are necessary for this problem.

Comment: I believe it is something wrong with the problem statement. More than one common normal exists at any large integer $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only parabola normal passing through $(0,0)$ or parallel to the axes is $x=0$ and it is always normal to the ellipse. Thus, we can parametrize every other potential normal as
$$
\frac xp+\frac yq = 1.
$$

Together with normal for parabola equation ($2y/q=4/p$) at point $x,y$, we get:
$$
p=2+x,\qquad q=\frac{2+x}2y\\
\text{and since $y^2=4x$:}\qquad q^2 = p^2(p-2)
$$

Doing the same thing with ellipse ($2x/a^2p+2y/63q=0$), we get:
$$
p=x\left(1-\frac{63}{a^2}\right),\qquad q=y\left(1-\frac{a^2}{63}\right),\\
\text{and since $x^2/a^2+y^2/63=1$:}\qquad a^2p^2+63q^2=(a^2-63)^2
$$

Now we can formulate the question as

> What is the largest parameter $a$ such that curves (1) $q^2=p^2(p-2)$ and (2) $a^2p^2+63q^2=(a^2-63)^2$ do not intersect$^*$?

One can show that $p_1=2$ is the minimal $p$ value of (1) and $p_2=|a-63/a|$ is the maximum $p$ value of (2). Solving $p_1=p_2$ gives you two values of $a=7$, $a=9$. So if $a\in[7,9]$, then there is only one common normal.

[image]

${}^*$ intersection where $p\neq0$, since $p,q\neq 0$ from the equation of normal

Comment: Sir, kindly explain this step : normal for parabola equation (2y/q=4/p)

Comment: Given, the equation $y^2=4x$, infinitesimal displacement $(dx,dy)$ along the tangent suffice $2ydy=4dx$ (in general, for $f(x,y)=0$, $f'_xdx+f'_ydy=0$). This displacement should also be made in the direction of gradient of the normal line $L=x/p+y/q-1=0$. Thus, we can set the displacement $(dx,dy) = \nabla L = (1/p,1/q)$.

Comment: You don't need to actually do this step (it's just a quick way to find normals). You can find the equation of normal to the parabola the way you know, then transform the equation to form $x/p+y/q=1$ and find $p,q$.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help.